# Chunk upload to Windows Azure Blob by using WCF REST

Tags: wcf, rest, upload, azure-storage, chunks

I'm using Windows Azure Blob Storage and WCF REST Services together to upload large files with chunk.

I can upload one part files easily, but I have to find a method to merge this chunks in an Azure Blob. What is the best practise to do this?

This is my interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate="Upload?name={name}&chunk={chunk}&chunks={chunks}")]
int Upload(string name, string chunk, string chunks, Stream fileContents);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BlockBlob solved my problem. I can upload huge files as 256kb chunks easily. Here is the example which helped me: 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Silverlight-Azure-Blob-3b773e26

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak of how to interact with WCF, but if you need to improve your upload performance, you should look at using the block access pattern and running multiple threads.

http://rob.gillenfamily.net/2010/09/13/maximizing-throughput-in-windows-azure-e28093-part-1/#fbid=51un4MimSGt

Erick